# $if \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = L$, then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(bx)}{x} = bL$ A particular question

Tags: calculus

Using the definition of limits, prove that $if \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = L$, and $b$ is different from $0$, then

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(bx)}{x} = bL.$$

The hypothesis tells us that $0 < |x| < \delta $ implies $|\frac{f(x)}{x} - L| < \epsilon $.
Let $0 < |x| < \delta$. Then

$$\bigg|\frac{f(x)}{x} - L\bigg| < \epsilon.$$

Then, $$\bigg|\frac{f(bx)}{x} - L + \frac{f(x)}{x}- \frac{f(bx)}{x}\bigg| < \epsilon.$$
Then,

$$\bigg|  b\frac{f(bx)}{x} - bL + b\frac{f(x)}{x}- b\frac{f(bx)}{x}\bigg | < b\epsilon.$$

$$\bigg| b\frac{f(bx)}{x} - bL\bigg| -\bigg|  b\frac{f(bx)}{x}-b\frac{f(x)}{x} \bigg| < b\epsilon.$$

In particular, $$\bigg |  b\frac{f(bx)}{x} - bL\bigg| < b\epsilon.$$
So

$$\bigg|  \frac{f(bx)}{x} - \frac{bL}{b}\bigg|< \epsilon.$$
I am stuck here. This is very near to prove what I want, but it clearly differs by a b: $ |  \frac{f(bx)}{x} - L| < \epsilon $ is different than
$ |  \frac{f(bx)}{x} - bL| < \epsilon $. I saw the answer here> [How to answer the question from Calculus by Michael Spivak Chapter 5 Problem 14](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730220/how-to-answer-the-question-from-calculus-by-michael-spivak-chapter-5-problem-14) And also in the Spivak answers book, but the approach to the proof is different. Maybe someone could help me finish the proof using the argument I gave, or otherwise explain in which part I am wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Hint: Do a change of variable $y=bx$ on the expression $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(bx)}{x}$.

Comment: @CheeHan Bad advice. The idea behind the question is to prove that 'change of variable' is formally justified.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 ahhhhh, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: $b>0$ or arbitrary?

Comment: What will happen if we set $b=0$?

Comment: b is different from 0. If it were 0, the division wouldn't be possible , so there would not exist a limit , and f(bx) would be f(0)

Comment: Then edit your post by stating that $b\neq 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its hard to follow your proof. Lets try to improve it. Assume $b\neq 0$. We know that we can find $\delta^*>0$ such that if $0<|x|<\delta^*$ then $$\bigg|\frac{f(x)}{x}-L\bigg|<\frac{\epsilon}{|b|}.$$ Take 
$$\delta=\frac{\delta^*}{|b|}$$
Thus, if $0<|x|<\delta$ then $0<|bx|<\delta^*$ and so
$$\bigg|\frac{f(bx)}{x}-bL\bigg|=\bigg|b\cdot\frac{f(bx)}{bx}-bL\bigg|=|b|\cdot\bigg|\frac{f(bx)}{bx}-L\bigg|<|b|\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{|b|}=\epsilon.$$

Comment: Could you please answer what happens if $b = 0$.