# Epsilon-Delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, epsilon-delta

The defintion give me a confusion. It states that
for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that, whenever $|x−a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)−L|<ϵ$.
So when I think about $|x−2|<\delta$ $\to$ $|x^2 -1| < \epsilon$. It is also true for every $\epsilon >0$ since I just need to choose large $\delta$ such that $f(x)=x^2$ on $|x−2|<\delta$ contain $|x^2-1|<\epsilon$

Comment: Choosing large $\delta$ will not really help. In fact, your $\delta$ needs to be small if $\epsilon$ is small. For example, if $\epsilon = 0.1$, then picking $\delta=10$ will not do. This is because taking $x=11$ means the inequality $|x-2|<\delta$ is true, but $|x^2-1|<\epsilon$ is not, therefore, the statement $|x-2|<\delta\implies |x^2-1|<\epsilon$ is also false.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So the definition mean "for all x in $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$" but  not  "for some x in $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$"?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4126198/confused-on-how-we-choose-delta-in-epsilon-delta-proofs/), and the answers by Ethan Bolker and Arthur, seem likely to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit in the example is
$$\lim_{x \to 2} x^2 = 1.$$
The definition of the limit is:
$$\forall \epsilon> 0, \exists \delta > 0, |x-2|<\delta \Rightarrow |x^2-1|<\epsilon.$$

First of all, when we see *$0<|x-2|<\delta$*, we talk about $x$-coordinate. But when we see $|x^2-1|<\epsilon$, we talk about $y$-coordinate.

But, I will follow your thought.
Look at the quantifier $\forall \epsilon$. If you choose large $\delta$, for instance $\delta = 10$. So that $|x-2|<10 \Longleftrightarrow -8<x<12$. We may choose $x = 8$ so,
$$|x^2-1| = |8^2-1|=63.$$
Because the quantifier of $\epsilon$ is $\forall$ positive epsilon, we may choose $\epsilon = 1$. It is clear that
$$|x^2-1| = 63 > \epsilon.$$

So the definition of limit is not true. In fact, the limit is not equal to 1.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your answer.  The correct definition of a limit as $x$ **approaches** $(a)$ is $$\cdots ~\color{red}{0 < } ~|x-a| < \delta ~\cdots $$